# Simple "== x OR y" in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, equals

I have a loop in which I check for numbers. Something like this, more or less:

```
<?php $counter = 0; ?>
<?php /* The loop */ ?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php $counter++; ?>
  <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
  <?php if ($counter == (2 || 4)) : ?>
     // DO SOMETHING
  <?php endif; // counter ?>
...
```

But `$counter ==(2||4)` returns true for every number (1, 2, 3, 4 etc.). I also tried:

- `$counter == 2 || 4`
- `$counter === 2 || 4`
- `$counter == (2 or 4)`

But to no avail. The first and last one also return true for every natural number and the second one never returns true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate solution would be to do the following:

```
$allowed = array(2, 4);
if (in_array($counter, $allowed)) {
    // good value
}
```

The advantage of this is that you can extend the list of allowed values very easily, maybe even placing them in an external config.

Answer (score 2):

simply replace

```
if ($counter == (2 || 4)) :
```

with

```
if ($counter == 2 || $counter == 4) :
```

see also the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to check for multiple values inside a condition like that.
This is one reason why php sucks... you're are forced to use two conditions, like

```
if($counter == 2 || $counter == 4)
```

or if you want to trigger your conditions on even numbers

```
if($counter % 2 == 0)
```

someone mentioned `in_array()` but you should know that arrays are very expensive in php in terms of resources.

Comment: You can easily check multiple values with arrays and in_array function in PHP.

Comment: yes u can, but consider what the compiler is producing. it is actually creating an array internally with all the hashes and stuff then comparing each value of the array to the values u list. all this for a simple condition that should compare 1 value with 2 other values

Comment: @thelolcat Please be consistent in your use of == vs === they mean very different things.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something when the counter is even, you can use the following:

```
<?php if ($counter % 2 === 0) : ?>
    // do something
    // will match 0, 2, 4, 6, ...
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `(2 || 4)` will always return true. This is because both operands to the `||` operator are non zero valued constants. It is essentially equivalent to `(true || true)` which is always `true` as is `(false || true)`.

the expression

```
$counter == (2 || 4)
```

will yield true except when `$counter` is 0

You want to write

```
($counter === 2 || $counter === 4)
```

note that you should always use `===` instead of `==` because the latter performs type coercion on its operands.